# Google Analytics: is there a way to re-trackPageview

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a situation where `_trackPageview` will be called. Then, **afterwards** I have a `_customVar` populated.

Is there any way to get this into the page tracking without doing another `_trackPageview` or `_trackEvent`. We don't want duplicate page views, and we don't want to interfere with existing event-based reports.

Comment: I send a virtual pageview to a non-existing directory after I set the custom var and exclude this directory via a profile filter. So far that seems to work.

Comment: thanks, that'll work too. I'm trying to find a way without any need to make changes in the GA account itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You need to send some kind of hit. It's usually better to fire with a dummy Event that is non-interactive.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'name', 'val', 1]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'CV', 'set', '', 0, true]); //non interactive event
```

you can also use another hit type like [Social](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial) or [Timming](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTiming) event. That will make it not show up on the event reports and if you don't use Social or timing reports it might be good. But I would recommend sticking to the normal Event and just ignore it from the reports.

Comment: Be sure to set the `opt_noninteraction` flag to true (as @Eduardo did in his example), to make sure that event doesn't effect the bounce rate calculations.